# How can a validator node earn trust on the network?

Tags: validators, scp

It's my understanding the SCP achieves consensus by having validator nodes agree with other validator nodes that they trust.  Anyone can become a validator node, but won't they not actually be participating if nobody trusts them?  How does a new node become trustworthy?  Would I need to like talk to people in real life, or can it happen by somehow doing a good job validating?

Answer (score 1):

Ask people in the validators slack channel to add you to their quorum set. It also helps if you add yourself to the default qset by making a pull request.

Comment: Ok so it's a person to person communication thing, not something I can earn programmatically?